Google Cloud Logging not capturing log for some services
I'm using Google Cloud Logging for my flask app.
The python logger is set with google's CloudLoggingHandler, and it's being used by the flask app itself and also other many services that runs independently using cli (it's also part of the same flask project)
The problem that I'm facing is that there is times when logs from some services are not being captured/sent to the google cloud logging.
So far, the only way to make the log be captured in cloud logging is by restarting the services, which I don't think is ideal to do frequently.
I've tried checking if there's an error/exception occurring when initializing the logger in each services but couldn't find any.
Here's how I currently implement the Cloud Logging Handler
import base64
import json
import google.cloud.logging
import logging
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler

GCP_LOGGER_CLIENT = None

def set_logger(log_name: str = "CORE") -> logging.Logger:
    try:
        global GCP_LOGGER_CLIENT
        if GCP_LOGGER_CLIENT is None:
            info = json.loads(
                base64.b64decode(config.GCP_LOGGING_CREDENTIAL).decode("utf-8")
            )
            credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
                info)
            GCP_LOGGER_CLIENT = google.cloud.logging.Client(
                credentials=credentials)
            logging.info("GCP_LOGGER_CLIENT logger initialized")

        GCP_LOGGER_CLIENT.setup_logging()
        handler = CloudLoggingHandler(
            GCP_LOGGER_CLIENT, name="CORE-LOG", resource=None)

        logger = logging.getLogger(log_name)
        logger.addHandler(handler)

        return logger
    except Exception as e:
        logging.critical("Failed to initialize cloud logger: ", str(e))
        raise


app_logger = set_logger("app")
error_logger = set_logger("error")

app_logger.info("Test")


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
